# Q: An infinite subset $E$ of a compact set $K$ has a limit point in $K$

Tags: analysis

I'm having difficulty following this proof and was hoping someone could help give a clear picture of what Rudin is doing.

**pf**
If no point of $K$ were a limit point of $E$, then each $q \in K$ would have a neighborhood $V_{q}$ which contains at most one point of $E$ (namely, q, if $q \in E$).  It is clear that no finite subcollection of $\{V_{q}\}$ can cover $E$; and the same is true of $K$, since $E \subset K$.  This contradicts the compactness of $K$.

I'm not exactly understanding the construction of $V_{q}$... if we have $q \in E$ then is $V_{q}$ by definition not a neighborhood by the construction of $V_{q}$?  Ie. if $q' \in E$ and every point around it is in $E$, then $V_{q'}$ is not a neighborhood, but just a point?

Comment: The "at most one point" can be a little confusing. It'd be enough to remark that it would cotain at most a finite number of points of $\;E\;$. Now, what's the definition of limit point? Well: $\;q\in K\;$ *is a limit point* of $\;E\;$ if **for any neighborhood** $\;V_q\subset K\;$ of $\;q\;$ there exists $\;e_q\in E\;\;s.t.\;\;e_q\in V_q\;$ . Now, negate this definition...and you have what's described in the above proof.

Comment: I think I see. There does not exist a point $q\in K$ which is a limit point of $E$.  Then every $q$ is $isolated$ from $E$.  Then, constructing $V_{q}$ to be neighborhoods of every $q$ such that at most one point is touched by $V_{q}$, namely $q$ if $q \in E$.  Then $\{V_{q}\}$ is an open covering of $E$.  But clearly there is no finite subcollection which covers $E$, given $E$ is infinite.
$$.$$
I think it was my understanding of the negation of limit point (isolation point).  So around every point we can create a neighborhood which contain no other points in $E$ not equal to itself.

Comment: Still trying to get a grasp on the definitions... Thanks!

Comment: @David Jhoo: Yes, this is a correct reasoning. You can now answer your own question and accept the answer.